# How to pass GUID as a Pex argument in pex

Tags: moles, pex

How I can pass GUID as a Pex argument using PexArgument attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.  From the [MSDN attributes tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454.aspx)

> Attribute parameters are restricted to constant values of the
>   following types:
>
> - Simple types (bool, byte, char, short, int, long, float, and double)
> - string
> - System.Type
> - enums
> - object (The argument to an attribute parameter of type object must be a constant value of one of the above types.)
> - One-dimensional arrays of any of the above types

You could just remove the `Guid` parameter from the generated `PexMethod` and hardwire the value:

```
[PexMethod]
public string MyFunction()
{
    Guid guid = Guid.Parse("394865F4-94AB-4B06-B00D-F66CD2CECE7D");
    string result = MyClass.MyFunction(guid);
    return result;
    // TODO: add assertions to method MyClass_Test.MyFunction(Guid)
}
```